# Is there anyway to use manual payments?

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce

I'm trying to create manual payments within Craft Commerce so the customer doesn't have to enter their credit card but every time I use the checkout button it says that the payment information is invalid. Is there anyway to have customers checkout without credit card info?

Answer (score 2):

You need to create a 'Manual' payment gateway in `Commerce > Setting > Payment Methods` This will allow the customer to choose the manual payment method on checkout.

The 'Manual' payment method is the only way a customer can submit an order without payment information. This gateway does not place any validation on the payment form action, so you should not see any errors. If you are seeing errors, make sure you are sending the ID of the manual payment method with the `paymentMethodId` param to the payment form action.

The 'Mark as Complete' is a separate action that allows those that have the 'Manage Orders' permission, to turn a Cart that is in progress into an Order:

[image: Order Edit screen in the CP]

Comment: Thats what i currently have it set to but when i click the submit order button i get a "payment information submitted is invalid" message

Comment: I also read that theres a complete order button with a paid version of craft?

Comment: If you don't have the paid version of craft commerce, you don't have access to the manual payment method.

Comment: @LukeHolder I'm using this method as well and it's going though fine.  However, the 'Total Paid' is not being set to $0, but to the order 'Total'.  How can I fix this?

Comment: @LukeHolder Never mind.. I set the payment type to Authorize only to resolve this.